# Entity Framework 1-1 and 1 to *

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, relationship

thank you all for taking the time reading my question. So I have 1 table called User that has 1-1 relationship with the table Demographics. This table has a relationship 1 to * with the table Industry. I'm not sure how to add all the info to context. I pass all the necessary information to the service method but I can't make it work without an error. They only thing that works is the initial add to demographics table. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks again! (If you need more code let me know)

```
public class DemographicIndustryRoomateVM
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public Education Education { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public FamilyStatus FamilyStatus { get; set; }
        public Work Work { get; set; }
        public int Roommates { get; set; }
        public FinancialStatus FinancialStatus { get; set; }
        public List<RoomateRelation> RoomateRelations { get; set; }
        public List<Industry> Industries { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
public async Task<HttpStatusCode> AddDemographicInfo(DemographicIndustryRoomateVM demographic)
        {
            var demo = new Demographic();
            demo.User = demographic.User;
            demo.City = demographic.City;
            demo.Country = demographic.Country;
            demo.Gender = demographic.Gender;
            demo.Age = demographic.Age;
            demo.FamilyStatus = demographic.FamilyStatus;
            demo.Work = demographic.Work;
            demo.Roommates = demographic.Roommates;
            demo.FinancialStatus = demographic.FinancialStatus;
            _context.Demographics.Add(demo);
            foreach (var roomrel in demographic.RoomateRelations)
            {
                _context.RoomateRelations.Add(roomrel);
            }
            foreach (var ind in demographic.Industries)
            {
                _context.Industries.Add(ind);
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
        }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.Industries_dbo.Demographics_DemographicID\". The conflict occurred in database \"test", table \"dbo.Demographics\", column 'ID'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated.